# 403 error when trying to disable billing to stop usage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify) and created a Cloud Function to cap (disable) billing to stop usage.

When I test my function, I have this 403 error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/projects/None/billingInfo?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

All rights are activated:

- Billing > "billing account administrator" for service account linked to function.
- IAM > role: "owner".

Answer (score 2):

I found, need to push an env variable:

PROJECT_ID = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')